# ASP.Net Razor Web Application Connect to LocalDB issues; Database does not exist in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, razor, connect

I'm programming a Razor website from the Ground up using VS 2013.  I started with a blank Web Application Project and slowly added files and functionality to suit what I need.  Basically its just jquery ui, css, and a few basic test webpages.

Keep in mind, I have added a reference to: WebMatrix.Data.dll

Now when I try to connect to my database, I use the following code:

```
@{
Layout = @"~\_SiteLayout.cshtml";
Page.Title = "Main Tabs";
var DB = Database.Open("NASDB");
var QString = "SELECT * from Tabpage";
}
```

But this code doesn't work.  It says "Database does not exist in this context."

But when I use this code everything works:

```
@{
Layout = @"~\_SiteLayout.cshtml";
Page.Title = "Main Tabs";
var DB = WebMatrix.Data.Database.Open("NASDB");
var QString = "SELECT * from Tabpage";
}
```

This is functional, but not easily readable.  Is there any way to fix this?  So just Database will work.  I also have to have the "Copy Local" property of the "WebMatrix.Data" reference set to true.  Is there any way to avoid this as well?

Comment: The easiest way to do this would have been to use the New Web Site option and then choose Razor Web Pages. Web Pages are designed to work with the Web Site project type, not the Web Application project type.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not want to resort to that.  Since creating a Razor Website using that methods adds a lot of stuff that I didn't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At The top of the page:

@using Webmatrix.Data

or you can add a reference in the webconfig file that exists in your views folder.

Comment: How do I include it in the webconfig?

Comment: Something like: `<add namespace="Webmatrix.Data" />`  I  know you are new but you should be doing all of your database queries in a controller (or some service layer) and passing to your view a strong typed object.  It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Cool.  Thank you for you answers so far,  but I'm gonna see just how much I can learn.  As far as webdesign is concerned I come from a mostly PHP/MySQL background.  What do you think is the most vital think about ASP.NET that I need to learn.  Because I have no idea what you are talking about when it comes to MVC.

Comment: I think your best bet to learn MVC is to not start out wrong. Build a simple controller/action and view for that controller.  Have the controller's action pass a strongly typed object to the view and maybe display that on the view.  Don't do any DB work in the view, that would all be done in the controller.  There are tons of tutorials to help you out!  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views